# MySQL Error - Php

Tags: php, mysql

When I go to the page, I get 4 errors, but when I execute the script it works perfectly and once it reloads the page after the scirpt has executed the errors go away. And the thing is I am using a password to connect and I am not connecting to localhost.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'a1160699'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a1160699/public_html/stockupdate/index.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a1160699/public_html/stockupdate/index.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'a1160699'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a1160699/public_html/stockupdate/index.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a1160699/public_html/stockupdate/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: Make sure your user you are using exists on the server you are executing this code on

Comment: whats the code on line 16 to 17 in index.php?

Comment: You are not using password.

Comment: @yassine__ It's a user error, not a code error

Comment: What do you mean @AndyHolmes

Comment: @Kyle The error is saying that the username and password you have in your mysql connection array doesn't match one that is set up for that database on the server you are running your code on.

Comment: They are though, I have checked multiple times, they are correct. @AndyHolmes

Comment: @Kyle the error is stating that the user and password you have set does not exist. *Access denied for user 'a1160699'@'localhost' (using password: NO)* this means you are not using a password in your array

Comment: Nevermind, thank you Andy, I see that my Username is incorrect, Ill change it and see if that fixes it :) @AndyHolmes

Comment: @Kyle you're most welcome. MySQL_* functions are deprecated now, i would suggest you look at using a more up to date model like PDO or MySQLi :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes It still is providing the error, this is my php code inside index.php

Comment: @AndyHolmes
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
require 'connect.php';
}
{

$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$sql = "UPDATE amount ".
       "SET amount = $amount " ;
mysql_query( $sql );
mysql_select_db('amount');
}
?>

Comment: You need to check connect.php, that's where the connection array is

Comment: @AndyHolmes
<?php
$username="a1160699";
$password="***********";
$database="a1160699_rsg4s";
mysql_connect("mysql3.000webhost.com","$username","$password");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
?>

Comment: 2 seconds, going to update my answer

Comment: Updated. Please comment on my answer instead of here now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user
>   'a1160699'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/a1160699/public_html/stockupdate/index.php on line 16

This line is indicating that your user you have set in your connection array does not have the required permissions and/or does not exist on the server you are attempting to run your code on. You will need to check that the username and password matches one that has the correct permissions on your MySQL server.

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
    $username="a1160699"; 
    $password="passwordHere"; 
    $database="a1160699_rsg4s"; 

    mysql_connect("mysql3.000webhost.com", $username, $password); 
    mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 
?>
```

Try this code in your connect.php file. This is MySQL to fit your code but I would **strongly** suggest you look at **MySQLi** or **PDO**.

Comment: Did you use the code above? I unquoted your variables to see if it would change anything

Comment: Does your user on your mysql server actually have a password assigned to it?

Comment: Yes it does, it is required to make one when you create a server.

Comment: then are you sure the host is correct, the password is 100% matching and the username is 100% correct? Something you have done in your connection array doesn't match the server

Comment: and have you checked that the user has the correct permissions for the database you are trying to select?

Comment: No I haven't checked that the user has the correct permissions. How do I do that?

Comment: It'll be in the bit where you create a user on your server i would imagine. It's likely that this is your entire issue lol

Comment: A lot of people have told me to edit my permissions but I can't see an option anywhere.

Comment: Where is your site hosted?

Comment: I'm using 000webhost free hosting until my website is complete as it is developing stage and don't want spend money until my website is perfect for use. I have read a tutorial and it says I need to use SSH

Comment: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/22769-mysql-permissions-privileges.html - does this help?

Comment: Quoted by an Administrator "Only premium users are allowed to use remote MySQL connections."

Comment: Thanks Andy :) I did submit a ticket to them but they never replied.

Comment: Sounds like you can't do it then :( You're more than welcome for the help. If this has helped you please feel free to mark as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that you have invalid MySQL credentials - either the user does not exist, or the password you're using is wrong. It appears that you're not using any password, so you might have just missed to input the password.

In case the username and password are correct, you should make sure that this user has the necessary permissions to interact with this database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a password for the localhost server then please connect your application in localhost server like this.

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','your passwrd');
mysql_select_db('your databse name');
```

After you can execute your query to database then it will work fine..

Comment: While valid, please do not suggest MySQL functions as they are deprecated